# Prepping fish from lake

Tags: fishing

I am looking to start prepping some of the fish I catch. I usually catch smaller perch! Do you have to let the fish bleed out or could you fillet it without bleeding out

Answer (score 2):

Just cut the head off, gut it and chop gills and fins(fins are up to you), then once you're done - wash it in a bucket with water after. No need to wait

Comment: I'm used to trout. I gut it then rinse, then I put lemon-pepper and butter on it, wrap it in aluminum foil (couple of layers, like baked potato) and let the campfire cook it.